# Display Custom Field or Custom Taxonomy in front page /post/product

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I added some custom field and taxonomy in  post /page/product main like Type, Channels, Battery etc.I created with custom post type UI plugin & ACF plugin but it is not showing in frontend of post page or product page. How do i show it ?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the theme you're using if it has the functionality to show the information. Usually, if you had a custom attribute using default WP, it will show those but for advance custom fields you might need to add the code into your theme.

For example, the following code will help you to display the field name and values

```
<?php
//https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/howto-show-all-acf-fields-and-there-labels/


    $fields = get_fields();
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value){?>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach( $fields as $field ): ?>
                <li><?php echo $key; ?>: <?php echo $value; ?></li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php
    }
?>
```